# Is the permutation of a Gaussian random vector still a Gaussian random vector?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n})$ is a Gaussian random vector with probability density function $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}(\det \Sigma)^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x - \mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu)}$$ where $\mu = (\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\Sigma = (\textrm{Cov}(X_{i}, X_{j}))_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}$.

Let $\sigma$ be any permutation of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. Then is $(X_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, X_{\sigma(n)})$ still a Gaussian random vector? For example, is $(X_{2}, X_{1}, X_{3}, X_{4}, \ldots, X_{n})$ still a Gaussian random vector?

I think the answer is yes. I found a fact that $(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n})$ is a Gaussian random vector if and only if $a_{1}X_{1} + \cdots + a_{n}X_{n}$ is normally distributed for all choices $a_{i}$. Then since $\sigma$ is a permutation the result follows. But is there a way to see this just from the pdf?

Comment: Yes - but you may need to adjust $\Sigma$ by suitably rearranging the rows and columns for the new permutation.